# Write to File With Recursion in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, recursion, parameters

I have a program that reads a string from a file, takes out all capital letters, then is supposed to store it in a file.  Thing is, I can't figure out how to write it to a file, short of creating a new file every time the function is called.

I guess what I'm really asking, is how can I pass a file into the function over and over again?  Can I pass a pointer parameter into the function again?

```
int main() {
FILE *inputFile;
inputFile = fopen("codedmessage.txt", "r");
char codedMessage[100];  // Will contain - HarjEtvyqaLbLdjlmO
char decodedMessage[100];
fgets(codedMessage, 100, inputFile);
FILE *outputFile;
outputFile = fopen("decodedmessage.txt", "r");
decode(codedMessage, strlen(codedMessage)-1, &decodedMessage);

return 0;
}

// Decodes the message and prints it to file
void decode(char msg[], int n, char dmsg[]) {
    if (!n) {
        if (isupper(msg[n])) {
            printf("%c", msg[n]);
            dmsg[n] += msg[n];
        }
    }
    else {
        decode(msg, n-1, *dmsg);
        if (isupper(msg[n])){
            printf("%c", msg[n]);
            dmsg[n] += msg[n];
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:  OS is Linux in general (Ubuntu and CentOS specifically)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you think you *couldn't* pass your `FILE *` to the function?

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's more straightforward to use ofstream, so I'll do just that. Basically everything I did was to:

- define outputFile as an ofstream;
- pass it to decode and write to it through the << operator.

You could instead change redirect stardard output to your file and simply write to standard output (you didn't need to change your decode function, it would work as is).

Even though the second process is simple, it is not as easy to understand. If you still want to use it: [C modifying printf () to output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947335/c-modifying-printf-to-output-to-a-file)

otherwise, here is a sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void decode(char msg[], int n, char dmsg[], std::ofstream& out);

int main() {
    FILE *inputFile;
    inputFile = fopen("codedmessage.txt", "r");
    char codedMessage[100];  // Will contain - HarjEtvyqaLbLdjlmO
    char decodedMessage[100];
    fgets(codedMessage, 100, inputFile);
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("decodedmessage.txt");
    decode(codedMessage, strlen(codedMessage) - 1, decodedMessage, outputFile);

    return 0;
}

// Decodes the message and prints it to file
void decode(char msg[], int n, char dmsg[], std::ofstream& out) {
if (!n) {
    if (isupper(msg[n])) {
        out << msg[n];    //This is what you want to print, is that correct?
        //printf("%c", msg[n]);
        dmsg[n] += msg[n];
    }
}
else {
    decode(msg, n - 1, dmsg, out);
    if (isupper(msg[n])){
        out << msg[n];
        //printf("%c", msg[n]);
        dmsg[n] += msg[n];
    }
}
```

}